# how to show IP address in localhost by using superglobals variable

Tags: php

I want to get the localhost IP address . I am using the php $_SERVER super global:

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 I get my IP address and see it is different from my IP address 
my output like this 
::1
my result is right or wrong how can we find it

Comment: your result is right

Comment: it's IPv6 address

Answer (score 0):

That's correct - it's an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

```
The result whatever you are getting is right..!!!

::1 is the actual ip address.
 It is an Ipv6 address in localhost
 If you use Ipv4 it will give 127.0.0.1 in localhost..
```